# Unable to deploy contract on public chain

Tags: mist, synchronization, contract-deployment, confirmations

I was trying to deploy a contract to public ethereum network using Mist. I was able to send transaction successfully but my transaction is get no confirmations. It has been around 45 minutes and my transaction is still on `0 out of 12 confirmations`. What could be the possible reason?

**Note**:

- I have sufficient ethers in my account (more than 1)
- I have tested the contracted on private testnet.
- My ethereum node is not synced to blockchain (still 142882 blocks to go)
- I have let Mist decide the fee for transaction.

**Edit :**
On Private-test Network:

- Estimated fee consumption=0.02485106 ether (1242553 gas)
- Provided max fee= 0.02685106 ether (1342553 gas)
- Gas used: 1243385

On Public net:

- Estimated fee: 1275193 gas
- Provided Max fee: 1375193 gas
- Gas used: 1375193

Also when I tried to track whether my transaction ran out of Gas using [ether.camp](https://live.ether.camp/), it could not find my transaction, same was with [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3737612e5f149266c8788e91bb12c260a778865983c65ecdeada49190c6f1858).How even can I track my transaction?

**Edit 2:** 
Mist [stopped syncing at block 2283415](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/1165), it is unable to download more peers from past 17 hours. I guess this may be a possible reason of why my transaction is not yet mined.

Comment: When deploying on your private network, what is the gas cost? The reason why I'm asking is that the gas limit on the public network has been set to a lower level to reduce the impact of the ongoing spam transactions since the start of Devcon2 a few weeks ago. From [Ethereum Network Status](https://ethstats.net/), the gas limit is currently 1,485,443. See also [The Ethereum network is currently undergoing a DoS attack](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/09/22/ethereum-network-currently-undergoing-dos-attack/).

Comment: I have edited the question. As I noticed on public net on clicking the transaction in `latest Transaction` tab, the gas used appears to be same as max gas provided, But the transaction has no confirmations yet. Has my contract deployment transaction ran out of gas?

Comment: perhaps it is because the Ddos attack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally my contract is deployed. Actually it was due to DDOS attack and many people were facing same kind of issue. After the [hard fork](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/10/18/faq-upcoming-ethereum-hard-fork/) based on  [EIP 150 version 1c](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/150), my transaction went through automatically yesterday (October 18). I am waiting for blocckckchain to sync to the block in which my contract was deployed so that I could verify if it is working fine.