# Accounts are not showing up in Mist 0.8.5 and 0.8.6

Tags: mist, accounts

I was [Unable to deploy contract on public chain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9216/unable-to-deploy-contract-on-public-chain), blockchain syncing was stuck on block 2283415, probably because of DOS attack. I updated my Ethereum-Wallet to latest version 0.8.5 and blockchain sync has crossed 2283415 blockno.
But now, my accounts are not showing up in Wallet. I followed the [this ques on stack](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4500/why-arent-my-accounts-keystore-files-showing-up-in-mist-etheruem-wallet), but didn't get any help. When I open developers tool of Mist and type `web3.eth.accounts` , it displays addresses of all my accounts. Also the keystore folder in `.ethereum` directory hold all accounts.

SO what could be the possible reason? The only possible problem I could think of is currently my Wallet is not in sync, there are still 37,000 blocks left, But If this is a problem, I don't understand why would it not let Mist display my accounts.Is there any issue with latest version of Mist? 

**Edit:**
The console of Ethereum-Wallet shows following error:

```
failed to load resource: file:///sockjs/info?cb=b9134hztuu
```

but web3.eth.accounts gives my account addresses.

**Edit 2:**
I deleted `.ethereum folder` (after taking solid backup), and then downloaded EthereumWallet 0.8.6, and was asked to enter password for creating an account for first time. Luckily this time I was able to see my this account on Mist, but as soon as I created a new account, again the new account didn't appear, I also imported my previous accounts but none shows up accept the one I created for first time(ethrebase). **How can I recover my account, I have real ethers in it.**

Comment: I don't know why no one yet come up with a solution. Now Mist 0.8.6 is released, maybe If I switch to this version my problem solves but I don't want to rely on maybe. Why there is no solid reason on why accounts are not appearing in Mist, and no concrete solution yet.

Comment: Did you copy the files from `keybase` back to `.ethereum/keybase` after the fresh install? Should work.

Comment: Yes I did.but nothing shows up in Mist. I even created a new account, a corresponding file is generated in `.ethereum/keystore` folder but account doesn't appear in wallet.

Comment: I suggest you escalate this to github, sounds like a bug.

Comment: hmm... I raised an [issue on github](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/1308). Don't know after how much time this will be resolved.