# Mist 0.8.6 crashing with Couldn't connect to node? See the logs for more

Tags: mist, memory

I have updated Ethereum-Wallet to 0.8.6. My [accounts were not showing up in Wallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9268/accounts-are-not-showing-up-in-mist-0-8-5), so I deleted the .ethereum folder (after taking a backup) and restarted Wallet, but now I was unable to run wallet, I was hit by pop-up screen displaying `Couldn't connect to node? See the logs for more`.

> Fatal: Could not open database: write /home/gemini/.ethereum/chaindata/029001.ldb: no space left on device

I currently have 2GB RAM, I added 4GB of swap memory but still geth consumes all memory and crashes.What could be the possible reason? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read your error message.

> Fatal: Could not open database: write /home/gemini/.ethereum/chaindata/029001.ldb: **no space left on device**

Your `$HOME` partition is full. Check it with `df -h`. It's not related to memory or swap, but you main hard disk.

Comment: Thanks. I resolved the issue, this was due to my device memory was full and I was thinking my Ram is not sufficient. But after making some free space, Mist finally launches, but [Accounts are still missing](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9268/accounts-are-not-showing-up-in-mist-0-8-5-and-0-8-6). Any help on that?