# Couldn't connect to node (Windows, Ethereum Wallet 0.8.8)

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, logs

What could be causing this   ?

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9372/mist-0-8-6-crashing-with-couldnt-connect-to-node-see-the-logs-for-more

Comment: Log looks good. Does that happen every time you launch mist?

Comment: I note you have installed on a Roaming profile. This is probably being backed up elsewhere if you are on a campus system and there may be restriction in setting up p2p servers. Perhaps try installing directly on the C: drive?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is uninstall Mist and download the latest version here:

https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases

Also you can use Metamask which is availabe as a chrome plugin.